# Matching polynomial coefficients when solving an equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Two polynomials of the same degree are equal if the they have the same coefficients. I would like to use that to find all coefficients of a polynomial:

```
f[x_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c; 
g[x_] := (x + 1)^2; 
Solve[f[x] == g[x], {a, b, c}]
```

But Mathematica returns

```
{{c -> 1 + 2 x - b x + x^2 - a x^2}}
```

I would like the answer to be $a=1, b=2, c=1$. `Solve` seems not to be the right function to do that. I need to indicate somewhere that the answer cannot depend on the variable $x$ as the coefficients are constant. Any idea which is the right function ?

The solution must be flexible to also solve variants of the problem such as:

```
f[x_] := a*(x-5)^2 + b*(x+1) + c; 
g[x_] := (x + 1)^2; 
Solve[f[x] == g[x], {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: Could use `SolveAlways[f[x] == g[x], x]`

Comment: Also `Solve[CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ (f[x] == g[x])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Carl mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244240/matching-polynomial-coefficients-when-solving-an-equation#comment614769_24424), [`SolveAlways`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) is the perfect solution here:

```
Clear[f, g, h, i]

f[x_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c;
g[x_] := (x + 1)^2;
SolveAlways[f[x] == g[x], x]

(* Out: {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1}} *)


h[x_] := a*(x - 5)^2 + b*(x + 1) + c;
i[x_] := (x + 1)^2;
SolveAlways[h[x] == i[x], x]

(* Out: {{a -> 1, b -> 12, c -> -36}} *)
```